# Sliding Cards Spacing Issue

Tags: html, css, scroll

- I have made some cards and restricted them from wrapping, thus making
  a card-wrapper which becomes container for **Horizontal Scrollable
  Cards**.
- I am Facing small issue. The **Last Card does not get any spacing** at
  the end..
- See below screenshot

[image]

```css
    html,
    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    body {
      background-color:#f4f4f4;
      margin: 0;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .card {
      display: flex;
      background-color: #fff;
      min-width: 100%;
      min-height: 200px;
      margin: 1rem;
      overflow-x: auto;
    }
    .card--content {
      background-color: #DED3EE;
      min-width: 200px;
      margin: 5px;
    }
```

```html
    <section class="card">
      <div class="card--content"></div>
      <div class="card--content"></div>
      <div class="card--content"></div>
      <div class="card--content"></div>
      <div class="card--content"></div>
      <div class="card--content"></div>
      <div class="card--content"></div>
      <div class="card--content"></div>
      <div class="card--content"></div>
      <div class="card--content"></div>
    </section>
```

Codepen Link : [Click](https://codepen.io/KrupeshAnadkat/pen/QVWPEP?editors=1100)

Any help?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: @Viira My desired output is to have some whitespace at the end of last card too. Just like all other cards have whitespace on left and right. Same behavior i want for last card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is switch your card spacing from margin to padding and add an inner container to each card.

Overflowing margin doesn't push the items within the parent container, rather it pushes the siblings outside. Since you have overflow hidden (by auto/scroll), it is effectively rendered `margin-right: 0;`

A relatively easy fix is to use padding instead. But you'll have to create an inner container so that you can use padding on the contents and so that the background-color is contained within the spacing.

You can see a working example here: https://codepen.io/rjhewitt3/pen/MqYjeg

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for this solution. 
 You should calculate `.card-track` width dynamicaly
This method use when creating image slider

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  background-color:#f4f4f4;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.card {
  background-color: red;
  width: 80%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.card-track {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: calc(200px*10 + 10px*10); /*Card content width x no of iems + margins */
}
.card--content {
  background-color: #DED3EE;
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<section class="card">
  <div class="card-track">
    <div class="card--content"></div>
    <div class="card--content"></div>
    <div class="card--content"></div>
    <div class="card--content"></div>
    <div class="card--content"></div>
    <div class="card--content"></div>
    <div class="card--content"></div>
    <div class="card--content"></div>
    <div class="card--content"></div>
    <div class="card--content"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Your answer solves the problem. But my page loads dynamically cards , it varies all the time. Number of cards is not fixed. I have many section and all can have different number of cards, that too is not fixed.
So can you suggest some other solution, Thanks